# Mocking 'this' in javascript qunit

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, grunt-contrib-qunit

if i have a Javascript function that uses, something like this...`$(this)[0].element.id;`

```
updateElement(){
$(this)[0].element.id;
}
```

I am using Qunit, is there a way i can mock `'this'` I would like to be able to test this function.

Comment: Do you have a larger code sample?

Comment: code smell,make this an argument of updateElement and it will be testable.  the goal of testing is refactoring bad code : http://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2014-01-25-the-failures-of-intro-to-tdd.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that `this` refers to some jQuery Object. You could create the respective objects using the jQuery function and then use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to attach the object as `this` to your actual function:

```
// prepare the DOM objects
var $elem = $( '...' );

// prepare a bound function
var boundFct = updateElement.bind( $elem );

// execute your function
boundFct();
```

Answer (score 3):

With the functions `apply` or `call` of the `Function` object, you can change the value of `this` when calling a function:

```
var mock = ...

updateElement.call(mock);
```

`this` will refer to `mock` inside the `updateElement` call above.